# layoutTitle tag issue

Tags: grails, gsp

Im working on the one grails project. So in it's main layout page there is a string

```
 <title>CHP: <g:layoutTitle /></title>
```

and every view page has a title tag. But I found that layoutTitle tag is overriden in HelperMethodsTagLib (within a same namespace) with this:

```
def layoutTitle = { attrs, body ->
        try {
            out << this.pageScope.settedPageTitle
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out << "Default"
        }
    }
```

this implementation doesn't work, so every page has title CHP: Default.
Deleting this implementation causes app to fall with this:

```
 2012-08-30 20:53:40,580 [http-8080-2] ERROR chp.HomeController  - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException
2012-08-30 20:53:40,591 [http-8080-2] ERROR pages.GroovyPagesServlet  - Error processing GSP: Error executing tag <g:layoutTitle>: java.lang.StackOverflowError at /home/aggressor/Job/chp/trunk/grails-app/views/layouts/user_page.gsp:5
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:layoutTitle>: java.lang.StackOverflowError at /home/aggressor/Job/chp/trunk/grails-app/views/layouts/user_page.gsp:5
    at home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp:23)
    at home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp)
    at home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp:25)
    at home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp)
    at home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp.run(home_aggressor_Job_chp_trunk_grails_app_views_layouts_user_page_gsp:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
    at chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)
```

Comment: What is the content of `chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty`?

Comment: I don't give a damn, it doesn't gave such method. Whet i try to call
`chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty(chp.HelperMethodsTagLib)` im having this 
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: chp.HelperMethodsTagLib.getProperty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class chp.HelperMethodsTagLib]`

Comment: Well you should give a damn, this method isn't created by Grails and that's causing the StackOverflowError...